# Samsung galaxy s5 and Samsung note4 fall under which dpi

Tags: android

I need  info about under which dpis both Samsung Galaxy s5 and Samsung note 4  like do they come under xxhdpi or xhdpi or hdpi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[S5](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s5-6033.php)** :

[xxhdpi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH)  [(~432 ppi pixel density)](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s5-6033.php)

**[note 4](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_4-6434.php)** :

technically it is [DENSITY_560](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_560)  since it has [~515 ppi pixel density](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_4-6434.php) ,

but you should target [xxxhdpi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXXHIGH) and let the android resources system scale images down for you [like the nexus 6](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)